# Coordinate representation on hyperboloid

Tags: differential-geometry

The problem is as follows; Consider the hyperboloid $^2 + ^2/4 − ^2/4 = 1$. $\\$
For any point on the hyperboloid, find a local chart and
compute the transition map between two non-equal overlapping charts.
$\\$ Now consider the function $(, , ) → ^2$ on this surface. Write down the coordinate representation of this function with respect to two different charts of your choice.

I have found all the local charts but I struggle to see, how I could write the coordinate representation of f wrt a local chart as

$\phi^+$ : (x, y, z) → (x, y) and therefore $(\phi^+)^{-1}$ : (x, y) → (x, y, +$\sqrt{1- x^2- y^2/4}$)

But thus I cannot express $(\phi^+)^{-1} \circ f$ because I am missing a component. I named f the function $(, , ) → ^2$.

Comment: We don't know the charts you are considering, and I'm pretty sure that you haven't found all of them: there are uncountably many local charts on manifolds...

Answer (score 1):

You did not tell in which charts it is asked to do the computations.
You have said that you have found them all, which I doubt.
Your $\phi^+$ presumably goes in pair with some $\phi^-$ built in the same way, but then $(\phi^+,\phi^-)$ will certainly not be an atlas.
So let me first choose an atlas for $H$.

First of all, the hyperboloid is no more than a curved version of a cylinder with ellipsoidal sections: any horizontal section $H\cap\{z=c\}$ is an ellipse given by the equation $x^2 + \left(\frac{y}{2}\right)^2 = \left(\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{z}{2}\right)^2}\right)^2$.
This observation leads us to notice that
$$
\begin{array}{r|ccc}
\varphi \colon & \Bbb S^1 \times \Bbb R & \longrightarrow & H \\
& ((a,b),z) & \longmapsto & \left(\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{z}{2}\right)^2}a, 2\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{z}{2}\right)^2}b, z\right)
\end{array}
$$
is a diffeomorphism.
An atlas for $\Bbb S^1$ thus yields an atlas for $H$.
Let us consider the stereographic atlas $\left\{\left(U_N,\psi_N\right),\left(U_S,\psi_S\right) \right\}$, where $U_N = \Bbb S^1\setminus \{N\}$, $U_S = \mathbb{S}^1\setminus \{S\}$, $N=(0,1)$ is the north pole, $S=-N$ is the south pole, and
$$
\psi_N(a,b) = \frac{a}{1-b},\quad \psi_S(a,b) = \frac{a}{1+b}.
$$
This now yields the two parametrizations of the circle:
$$
\psi_N^{-1}(t) = \left(\frac{2t}{1+t^2}, \frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2} \right),\quad \psi_S^{-1}(s) = \left(\frac{2s}{1+s^2},\frac{s^2-1}{1+s^2}\right).
$$

Hence, we have found two local parametrizations for $H$, given by $\varphi_N(t,z) = \varphi\left(\psi_N^{-1}(t),z\right)$ and $\varphi_S(s,z)=\varphi\left(\psi_S^{-1}(s),z\right)$.

Lastly, the expression of the map $f\colon (x,y,z)\in H \mapsto y^2\in \Bbb R$ in these parametrizations are simply $f_N=f\circ \varphi_N^{-1}$ and $f_S=f\circ \varphi_S^{-1}$, that is
$$
\begin{array}{r|ccc}
f_N\colon & \Bbb R^2 & \longrightarrow & \Bbb R \\
& (t,z) &\longmapsto & 4\left(1+\left(\frac{z}{2}\right)^2\right) \left(\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}\right)^2
\end{array},
$$
and
$$
\begin{array}{r|ccc}
f_S\colon & \Bbb R^2 & \longrightarrow & \Bbb R \\
& (s,z) &\longmapsto & 4\left(1+\left(\frac{z}{2}\right)^2\right) \left(\frac{s^2-1}{1+s^2}\right)^2
\end{array}.
$$
By chance, these two parametrizations give the same function (which isn't really a coincidence, due to the symmetries of the hyperboloid).